# SciPy Rounding Errors with Beta Distribution

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics

I'm using stats.beta.ppf(prob,alpha,beta) with very high probability values, for example 0.999999805056895.

This appears to be producing incorrect results (it looks like a rounding problem to me). When I do the same calculation in Excel the results are as expected.

Does anyone know how I can get the correct result in Python?

```
Excel Formula is: is =BETA.INV(J2,N2,O2)*H2 
Where J2 =0.999999805056895, 
N2 = 0.671166820760872,
O2 = 429675.55588237,
H2 = 8865918892259.66
```

The Excel result is 294,195,914. But Python produces 8,865,913,813,427.

Comment: Yes, edited above. Thanks

Comment: Another question about Scipy and beta quantiles; possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306538/unexpected-behavior-in-scipy-isf

Comment: Yes, could be, and it looks like that bug is still open!

Comment: On looking at this again, maybe there's a simpler problem. The Python result divided by H2 is 0.9999994271510125 while the Excel result divided by H2 is 3.318278878648959e-5. Are you unintentionally computing 1 - something instead of something? In any event it will clarify the problem to work directly with BETA.INV and its equivalent in Python.

Comment: No, the calculation is correct. I have 100,000+ rows of data and I'm getting the correct results for all but a handful of rows. The only rows where I get the incorrect result are when J2 is close to 1 e.g. 0.9999992

Comment: OK. Well, the difference between (small number) and (1 minus small number) makes me think maybe an incorrect branch is being taken in the Scipy code, then. That might be a different kind of bug than the one which is mentioned in the link above. Something to think about.